# Comparacion de datos en C++

Tags: c++

oy muy nuevo en esto de la programación y tengo la tarea de generar un programita en C++ que verifique un RUT (DNI Chileno) ingresado por medio del algoritmo modulo 11.

El algoritmo está bien aplicado y genera el resultado que se requiere en mi programa pero al momento de verificar el que el dígito resultante del calculo sea igual al dígito del rut ingresado por el usuario me da el problema.

Los RUTs a comprobar que tengan dígito K o 0 se muestran como correctos, pero todos los demás dígitos se muestran incorrectos aunque sean RUTs validos.

Creo que es un problema con la comparación final y los tipos de datos, pero no se como solucionarlo

Aquí va mi código

La declaración de la clase

```
class Rut {
private:
    string rut;
    char largo, guion, ceroinicial, digito;

public:
    Rut(string rut)
    {
        this ->rut = rut;
        this ->largo = rut.length();
        this ->digito = rut[9];
        this ->guion = rut[8];
        this ->ceroinicial = rut[0];
    }
```

La función de comparación

```
void verificaRut(){
            int suma = 0, resto;
            char resultado, dcorrecto;

            // Validaciones: largo de 10 caracteres, ausencia de 0 inicial y existencia del guión
            if (largo == 10 && ceroinicial != '0' && guion == '-' )
            {
                suma =  ((rut[7]-'0')*2) + //Se llama a la posición y al restarle '0' se pasa a int
                        ((rut[6]-'0')*3) +
                        ((rut[5]-'0')*4) +
                        ((rut[4]-'0')*5) +
                        ((rut[3]-'0')*6) +
                        ((rut[2]-'0')*7) +
                        ((rut[1]-'0')*2) +
                        ((rut[0]-'0')*3);

                resto = suma % 11;
                resultado = 11 - resto;

            }
            else {
                cout << "\nError en el formato del rut: debe tener 8 dígitos, no comenzar en 0, tener guion y dígito verificador"
                << endl;
            }

            if (resultado == 10){
                dcorrecto = 'K';
            }
            else if (resultado == 11){
                dcorrecto = '0';
            }
            else{
                dcorrecto = resultado;
            }

            if (dcorrecto == digito ){
                cout << "\nEl rut está correcto!" << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "\nRut está incorrecto! " << endl;
            }
        }
```

Y el main

```
int main () {
    string rut;

    cout << "Ingrese el rut a validar: "; cin >> rut ;
    Rut r(rut);
    r.verificaRut();

    getchar();
    return (0);
};
```

Espero me puedan orientar, muchas gracias de antemano.

RUTs para probar: 13415215-K el cual da correcto, 25254382-1 da incorrecto, aunque el RUT es valido.

Comment: Para los que no somos chilenos, podrías incluir en tu pregunta un par de datos de prueba y el resultado esperado, por favor? :)

Answer (score 1):

En el constructor, haces

```
this ->digito = rut[9];
```

Luego, en tu función `verificaRut( )`, haces

```
resto = suma % 11;
resultado = 11 - resto;
...
dcorrecto = resultado;
```

Y terminas con

```
if( dcorrecto == digito ) {
  cout << "\nEl rut está correcto!" << endl;
}
```

En resumen, tu variable `digito` contiene **un código ASCII**, mientras que tu variable `dcorrecto` contiene **un número**, menor de `11`. Eso, simplemente, **no va a funcionar nunca**.

Una posible solución es hacer lo mismo que haces en el resto del código, restar el valor ASCII del carácter `0`:

```
if( dcorrecto == ( digito - '0' ) ) {
  cout << "\nEl rut está correcto!" << endl;
}
```